# What is rectangle structure?

Tags: winapi

It so confusing to understand or imagine this explanation. is there a picture to describe this?. what it means left, top, right, bottom? i knows rectangle have four corner. the more confusing with subraction. rect can get width, and height.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windef/ns-windef-rectl

left:
Specifies the x-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle.

top:
Specifies the y-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle.

right:
Specifies the x-coordinate of the lower-right corner of the rectangle.

bottom:
Specifies the y-coordinate of the lower-right corner of the rectangle.

```
int width = rect.right - rect.left;
int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rectangle described by RECT structure has its sides parallel to screen edges.

Left, Right, Top and Bottom are distances (usually in pixel) from top-left screen corner.

[image: Just drawn a picture]

You can also see it as defined by two corner points, Top;Left and Bottom;Right. The other two would repeat coordinates from these two, so they are not needed.

Comment: left is means margin or position from initial x point? https://ibb.co/S74gXQQ. if so, when i want create rectangle width 100 length. it needs always to plus by margin or position? ex.   left 20. `Rect(20, 0, 120, 100)`?

Comment: Yes, to Right = Left + Width, Bottom = Height + Top. With plain WinAPI you have to do this addition on your own. With MFC/ATL C++ libraries, there's CRect class to wrap RECT, and it has a constructor that takes POINT and SIZE.